# How to inject JavaScript into a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fill the details in a web page automatically when the page is loaded. I found that this can be done using JavaScript injection,  but it is not working.

For example: here is the code of a simple webpage with one input field:

```
<html>
    </head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Enter your Name:</h1>
        <input type="text" name="xyz" id="Name">
    </body>
</html>
```

After loading the webpage I typed:
`javascript:document.getElementById("Name").value="Yougansh"`in the address bar
but instead of changing the value in input field it just displays "Yougansh".
Is it possible with JavaScript or do I need to use a different method?

Comment: just use value attribute <input type="text" name="xyz" value="Yougansh"  id="Name">

Comment: The value won't change in the page source because it shows the source at the time of page rendering. The actual value of the field will change, use Developer Tools to inspect the element and you'll see.

Comment: what do you mean by you typed: javascript:document.getElementById("Name").value="Yougansh"  ? Where did you type it ?

Comment: I typed the script in the address bar @Boney

Comment: if you are using chrome, there are plenty of 'query injector' type plugins that insert jquery into each page that can be customised. eg (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-everywhere/boedlnaajelklaajcckcnnjmooonmalf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The problem is when I run the document.getElementbyId() method in the address bar it returns a string value which is not being stored and therefore the browser displays that string on web page.
just added var a= before the statement i.e.

```
javascript:var a=document.getElementById("Name").value="Yougansh"
```